# Can't ping from Host machine (Linux Mint) to Guest Os (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, ping

I have a Linux mint installed on a dual boot system and on that I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu running on it. When I select the network card to NAT the guest pings to the host but the host doesn't ping the guest Os. And when I select bridged both of them don't work and it doesn't even give an IP to the virtual machine.

Comment: NAT behavior is working as expected.  Please edit your question to include network details/setup, like how are IP addresses served on your network, firewall settings for both, etc.

Comment: My apologies for the late response. As I'm new at networking I'll try to include as much as I can.

Comment: Ok so weirdly when I added another guest machine using virtual box, everything works host ping both guests and guests ping host and each other. I don't know how this happened but it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding another host, it solved everything.
I don't know how but it works